# dataframe.header and dataframe['header'] difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can use dataframe.header and dataframe['header'] to call up same result.
I can also use same function as dataframe.header.isnull() or dataframe['header'].isnull().

So what is the main difference between these two?

Comment: Nothing really, except that the latter, `.` attribute access, is much more error prone. This has been asked before, so I'll just close it and point to the dup.

Comment: Or reading [Attribute access](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access) section may help :)

Comment: @ALollz Thank you. Would you please show me the original question link?